# Zend 2: Unit tests for form class

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

I'm just starting using PHPUnit with Zend and need little help to figure out how these tests should work.

**I want to test if form return any error message if I do not pass any POST parameters.**

The problem is that one field from my form is using Doctrine's `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect`

```
    ...
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'name' => 'user',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'user-label',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'object_manager' => $em,
            'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\User',
            'property' => 'username',
            'label' => 'User:',
            'display_empty_item' => true,
            'empty_item_label'   => '---',
            'label_generator' => function($entity) {
                return $entity->getUsername();
            },
        ),
    ));
    ...
```

I get following error:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getIdentifierFieldNames() on null`

I tried override this field with mocked object, however Zend doesn't allow `objects` in `type`, just class name (`string`), so this code doesn't work:

```
public function testIfFormIsValid()
{
    $objectSelect = $this->getMockBuilder('DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $objectSelect->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getValueOptions')
        ->will($this->returnValue(array()));

    $form = new \AppModuleComment\Form\Comment('form', array(
        'em' => $this->em  // Mocked object
    ));
    $form->add(array(
        'type' => $objectSelect,
        'name' => 'user',
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'user-label',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'object_manager' => $this->em,
            'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\User',
            'property' => 'username',
            'label' => 'User:',
            'display_empty_item' => true,
            'empty_item_label'   => '---',
            'label_generator' => function($entity) {
                return $entity->getUsername();
            },
        ),
    ));

    $data = array(
        'id' => null,
        'user' => null
    );

    $form->setData($data);
    $this->assertTrue($form->isValid(), 'Form is not valid');
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I test such code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are testing functionality of Zend or Doctrine (or both) and not your own code. When you use libraries you should trust these libraries.

What happens is: `Form\Form::add()` uses `Form\Factory::create()` to create from the array an element. `Form\Factory::create()` uses `Form\FormElementManager::get()` to get an element from the given type.

Your type is an object and because `Form\FormElementManager::get()` can not handle objects your script will fail.

It seems you want to test that if post is empty `Form::valid()` calls `ObjectSelect::valid()` but this does not verify if the value is null. That's code from Doctrine / Zend not yours. Don't test it.

More interesting it gets when you want to mock the result of an select from within Doctrines `ObjectSelect`. But that's another question.

Comment: So.. how should I test If form returns validation messages if someone submit empty form? Or if form is valid if user provide correct data? I need Doctrine's functionality to test this

Comment: It seems you need more practice for writing unit tests. First of all: you don't write code inside your unit test - instead you run your code. I suggest playing with easier units before trying to test controllers that generating forms that using entity managers. You should be sure what is your unit that you want to test and if you want to use test doubles or have a fixed dataset and so on.

Comment: Maybe you are right I need more practice for writing tests. But you didn't explain how should I test forms and inputFilters connected with Doctrine.
I want to test if I'll get validation messages when user send empty form or he skip some inputs.
The reason I wrote code in my tests is that I wanted to show what I tried to make it working with Doctrine